# Having problems to implement a setOnClickListener - Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I'm having problems to implement an onclick to the items I have in my list. the error is below:

```
06-14 16:15:43.861  11651-11651/wk.gon250.dublinbike E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: wk.gon250.dublinbike, PID: 11651
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead
            at android.widget.AdapterView.setOnClickListener(AdapterView.java:778)
            at tab.Tab2.onCreateView(Tab2.java:67)
```

The code of my class is:

public class Tab2 extends Fragment
{
    static ListView listView;
    static CustomAdapter adapter;

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_2, container, false);
    String Url = "http://mypath";
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Please, Wait", "Loading..");

    listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listViewT_stations);

    JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Url, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                JSONObject jsonNetwork = new JSONObject(response.getString("network"));
                JSONArray stationsArray = jsonNetwork.getJSONArray("stations");
                StationJson[] stations = gson.fromJson(stationsArray.toString(), StationJson[].class);
                adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), stations, R.layout.station_item);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            progressDialog.cancel();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //Manage Error
            progressDialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    queue.add(req);
    listView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
    return v;
} }
```

I can't no use a `listFragment`, so any sugestion? How can I implement a onclick to the items I have to open a new view? and what is the best practice?

Thanks!!

Comment: use setOnItemClickListener instead of setClickListener ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says:

```
Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead
```

The `OnClickListener` is meant for click events on whole views. In an `AdapterView`, you usually want to register click events for each item separately. For this you need to use `OnItemClickListener`.